# is it Possible to upload the Landscape ScreenShot for application in to the Android Market?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, google-play

My application is nearing completion, but the problem is I have seen many applications that have portrait-oriented Screenshots of application.

But in my application I have landscape-orientation screen shots. So is it possible to upload such screenshots on Android Market, or do I have to select any specific option to upload such landscape screenshots for my application ?

Comment: Yes, you can upload landscape screenshots as well, there's no different way to do so. You have to upload landscape images in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can defiantly upload screenshot either in Landscape or Portrait..

there are many application in market..

[HOMERUN BATTLE 3D](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.com2us.HB3D&feature=search_result)

[Fruit Slice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.droidhen.fruit&feature=search_result)

[Angry Birds](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&feature=search_result)